# Channel Length Modulation in mos

Tags: nmos

The follwoing is a screenshot from [youtube](https://youtu.be/KnKEFbpTNrU?t=479).
[image]

According to the model on the left, it's easy to get
$$I_{DS} = I_{DSAT} + \frac{V_{DS}} {\frac{1} {\lambda I_{DSAT}}}
= I_{DSAT} + \lambda I_{DSAT} V_{DS} = I_{DSAT} (\lambda V_{DS} + 1)
$$

However, according to  the graph on the right
$$\lambda I_{DSAT} = \frac{I_{DS} - I_{DSAT}} {V_{DS} - V_{GT}}$$
$$\Longrightarrow I_{DS} = I_{DSAT} (\lambda V_{DS} + 1 - \lambda V_{GT})$$

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

The equation you derived based on the graph seems the correct approximation for the saturation region current because when VDS = VGT, you get IDS = IDSAT. The model is hence incorrect and needs to be fixed.